# Amplitude changes with in-built Matlab fft/ifft functions and frequency/time domain integration/differentiations

Tags: matlab, fft, numerical-integration, frequency-analysis

I have confusing results when using the matlab fft function in one of my projects, and would like to understand why.

I've implement the fourrier transform (by using the matlab fft function) on a measured **speed**, and then **integrate** that signal in the **frequency domain** (by dividing by i*omega). I then bring my signal back to the **time domain** by using the in-built matlab ifft function. I then **differentiate** the signal in the **time domain** (using the diff function), meaning I should get the same signal as my original speed signal.

I do get the same shape. However, I don't get the same values... Does anyone know why this is the case? How could I overcome this problem to regain my original signal?

```
speed_spectrum = zeros(sampsize,length(x));

sampsize = double(sampsize);
window = hanning(sampsize);     % hanning window

%Find size of file, delta T, sampling freq and delta F
deltat=1/sampfreq;          %Seconds
deltaf=sampfreq/sampsize;   %Hertz

%Creating frequency and time vectors
freq=0:deltaf:(sampsize-1)*deltaf;
time=0:deltat:(sampsize-1)*deltat;
```

Here I implement the fft on my speed signal:

```
for z2 = 1:length(x)       %Each matrix corresponds to measurement at point x(z2) along the beam
    for z=1:navg
        speed_spectrum(:,z2) = speed_spectrum(:,z2) + (fft(data(:,z2,z).*window))./navg;
    end
end
```

I integrate my signal in the frequency domain:

```
for z2 = 2:length(omega)
    position_spectrum(z2,:) = speed_spectrum(z2,:)/(1i * omega(z2));
end
```

I apply the ifft to bring my position signal back into the time domain:

```
position_tdomain = ifft(position_spectrum(:,:));
```

I then differentiate the position signal to get back to my speed signal:

```
speed_tdomain = diff(position_tdomain);
```

[image]

It's normal to see such large differences in the window form because of the hanning window applied.

But when zooming in, near the center (where the hanning window is equal to or close to 1), we can observe the same shape, but with different amplitudes:

[image]

Is this due to the integration in the frequency domain, and then the differentiation in the time domain, or rather by the fft and ifft functions?

Comment: The amplitude shape looks equal to me, it's only a scaling factor?

Comment: Yes I think so, but I don't understand it's there. I also tried doing the normalisation as shown in the matlab fft example by dividing or multiplying my final time signal by my sample size (16 000)  but didn't get the same values

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You cold generate a synthetic example (formula, some noise added), so people can follow your code w/o having to generate their own mockup data.